# USB ports do not work after attempting to boot from USB

Tags: usb

I just got a Raspberry Pi Model 4B with 8GB RAM. I put the USB Boot bootloader on an SD card to switch it to run off an external SSD, but when I tried actually booting, I had a black screen. I changed it back to SD boot, and now the Raspberry Pi OS loads (from the SD card), but the USB ports don't work (no power or anything to keyboards, mice, etc.). I would appreciate any help.